# Positive antonym of brunt?

Tags: antonyms

You're *taking the brunt* normally when a storm of bad events hits you the hardest and deals most harm to you.

How would you call it when a storm of mostly unrelated positive events leaves you receiving most (potentially undeserved or unasked for) benefits?

(it doesn't have to be a single word - a neat expression, like would be just as fine)

Comment: *garnering the benefits*

Comment: Note how "dodge the bullet" would be the other kind of antonym. @StoneyB: that seems to me as purposeful reaping of them, not just "falling victim".

Comment: To be sure, *garner* is often used today to mean *to earn*, and it is sometimes used in contexts where considerable effort is expended. But the root meaning of the word is *to store*, as in a granary, without respect to merit: "Some of these bloggers that supported Brian Moran consider the election result quite unfair, believing they did the heavy lifting while Deeds sat back and garnered the benefit." [LINK](http://virginiademocrat.blogspot.com/2009/06/final-word-on-terry-mcauliffe.html)

Comment: You can *take **the** brunt* - or more often - ***bear** the brunt [of something]*, but I've never come across *to take brunt* before. Where do you see this usage?

Comment: *Reap a windfall.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in poor English. Corrected.

Comment: @Autoresponder: as I checked the meaning... Submit this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @SF's response to my comment, am posting the phrase *to come into a windfall* as an answer.

*Bearing the brunt* refers to putting up with the worst of a bad situation/circumstance, while *to come into a windfall* or *reap a windfall* refers to the converse - sudden, unexpected good fortunes.

Answer (score 3):

You'd [get the lion's share](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22took%20brunt%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22get%20the%20lion%27s%20share%22&oq=%22get%20the%20lion%27s%20share%22&gs_l=serp.3...3624242.3630072.2.3630693.20.20.0.0.0.1.128.1113.19j1.20.0...0.0...1c.1._VwMdBQ8I34&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867) if you got most of the benefits.

Personally I think including *(potentially undeserved or unasked for)* in the request may be asking a bit much. OP might have to settle for an ["**undeservedly** lion's share"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22undeservedly%20lion%27s%20share%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

---

Both *windfall* (unexpected benefit) and *lion's share* tend to apply to a *single* event. For OP's "storm" of gains, perhaps [**hit a** lucky/**winning streak**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hit%20a%20lucky%20streak%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or [be **on a roll**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22i%27m%20on%20a%20roll%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=3&tok=6Z6EQ6DWIOkOzJ1fPy80Lg&ds=bo&pq=%22i%27m%20on%20a%20roll%22&cp=2&gs_id=9&xhr=t&q=%22I%27m%20on%20a%20roll%22&pf=p&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22I%27m%20on%20a%20roll%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867&bs=1) would be better.

In Britain, if people felt such a lucky winner was *undeserving* of his good fortune, they might say...

> [*The **jammy so-and-so** hit a lucky streak*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20jammy%20so-and-so%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20jammy%20so-and-so%22&oq=%22the%20jammy%20so-and-so%22&gs_l=serp.3...5282.9216.3.9712.10.10.0.0.0.1.312.783.9j3-1.10.0...0.0...1c.1.CxfWCPLjkj4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867) (or more likely, [*jammy **bastard***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20jammy%20so-and-so%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22jammy%20bastard%22&oq=%22jammy%20bastard%22&gs_l=serp.3...264807.271134.4.271405.20.20.0.0.0.2.111.1282.19j1.20.0...0.0...1c.1.mn-PNc2uADM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867)).

Comment: @WillHunting: I'd go for "lion's undeserved share" if anything... That might work in general for that, but in my case it's not entirely undeserved - it's a honestly earned but  disproportionately generous reward. [Specifically, the protagonist made a cup of excellent coffee for a god, and receives a reward which is only proportional by the god's standards, while all reap benefits of the god's excellent mood...]

Comment: I'm guessing _undeserved_ could be omitted more often than not, as that could probably be inferred from the context. In other words, if someone receives the lion share of good fortune for the week (say, by buying a winning lottery ticket in the same week they win a new car on a television game show), there's no need to add a qualifier.

Comment: @SF: Would it be the other people who inadvertently receive the god's fortune that are experiencing this "antonym of bear the brunt"?

Comment: @tylerharms: No, imagine the direct: there's an audit that reveals serious problems. Everyone loses christmas bonuses, but the manager is fired and fined on top of that - he takes the brunt. Now here everyone is receiving moderate benefits, but the protagonist gets a totally over-the-top reward.

Answer (score 1):

I would offer the idiom "to make hay" in this context. As in the full expression, "make hay while the sun shines," it suggests a temporary windfall that could be optimized without extraordinary effort.

> make hay:
>   to use an opportunity to get the most benefit.

"While oversight in the finance industry was minimal, I made hay by running a ponzi scheme."